# Is there a way to generate a gitignore from a makefile?

Tags: version-control, makefile

I have a lot of files such as JavaScript, HTML, and even C and C header (.h) files which are automatically generated, so they appear in the makefile like

```
myfile.js:    myfile.js.tmpl
```

etc. I want all of these target files to be ignored by the version control system. I am using git but this question is not git-specific. Is there a utility or a trick which exists to make the ignore file (like `.gitignore`) from a makefile?

(If there isn't such a facility, I can make a script to create one, but before I do that I am just checking I haven't missed some obvious tool or method.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to start with a clean checkout, do a build, then run a `git status` to find out which files are untracked. Add those files (or suitable patterns) to your `.gitignore` file.

Makefiles can be so complex that the only way to find out what they do might be to actually run them.

Comment: That's a good idea but unfortunately doesn't fit my problem. I have stupidly already added these files to version control, and so I need to remove them and then keep them removed.

Comment: @Kinopiko: If your Makefile has a "clean" function, run that followed by `git status` to find out which files are removed by clean. Then you can `git add -u` and `git commit` to remove those files from version control. If you don't have a working "clean" function, you'll have to remove these files manually first.